# SQLite package not found in Electron/TypeORM

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, electron, typeorm

I'm working on an app that's based on Electron (1.7), TypeORM (0.2.6), SQLite3 (3.1.13) & Ionic (3.19.1).

I'm trying to update the database dependencies to their latest versions (TypeORM 0.2.20 & SQLite3 4.1.0).

The project compiles correctly but when I run the app, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: SQLite package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install sqlite3 --save
```

Of course it's installed and its binding has been built through `electron-builder install-app-deps`:

```
node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/
├── electron-v1.7-darwin-x64
│   └── node_sqlite3.node
└── node-v57-darwin-x64
    └── node_sqlite3.node
```

What did I miss?